# visual studio express - is the OpenFilesDialog available?

Tags: visual-studio-express

Is the OpenFilesDialog available in Visual Studio Express - or just in the full version?

I have just installed Visual Studo Express 2008 and also 2012, and the only Toolbox categories I have in both versions are "Common WPF Controls" and "All WPF Controls" (and "General" which is empty).

Should I see more ?

Ian

Answer (score 0):

It is available. If you right click on ToolBox and click ChooseItems... You can add other controls.

It's under the `System.Windows.Forms` Namespace

If you are working with Windows Forms, it will be accessible through the "Design" view as described above.

If you are designing WPF applications, you will need to programmatically add an OpenFilesDialog (See this link: [C-Sharp Corner - OpenFileDialog in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/openfiledialog-in-wpf/))

Comment: It is selected under the ".Net Framework Components" tab of Choose Toolbox Items, but I don't see it in the Toolbox items that pop-out from the left side of the screen - ready for me to drag it onto my form.

Comment: If I de-select OpenFilesDialog from the Toolbox, then re-select it, I get the following error message: "The following dialog controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer:  OpenFileDialog.  Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET Framework version".   I have the final release version of .NET Framework 4.5 installed.

Comment: As you appear to be working on a WPF app, you may not have access in the designer but see [C# Corner - OpenFileDialog in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/openfiledialog-in-wpf/) for a sample how to.

Comment: "Be aware that the Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog shows a different dialog that the System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog" as seen in a comment from (BennyTordrup)[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/authors/BennyTordrup/bt.aspx] on that link and use the control that suits your need.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you all - this beginner didn't understand the difference between a Windows Form application and a WPF application.  If I start a Windows Forms application (not a WPF application), all the dialogs are there as they should be.